# Why does the error "expected to be a reference, value given" appear?

Tags: php

It fires out when I try to call function with argument by reference

```
function test(&$a) ...
```

through

```
call_user_func('test', $b);
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`call_user_func`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) can **only** pass parameters by value, not by reference. If you want to pass by reference, you need to call the function directly, or use [`call_user_func_array`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array), which accepts references (however this may not work in PHP 5.3 and beyond, depending on what part of the manual look at).

Comment: @Artefacto I left that out originally because the manual states that it's not the case in 5.3, but I've updated my answer.

Comment: I would call it directly as I've just had a case where a script works fine on my server with "call_user_func_array" but for my client it throws an error (I'm using 5.3.x and he must be too)...so it seems a bit of touch and go.

Comment: `ReflectionMethod` is similar: `invoke` does not work, whilst `invokeArgs` does pass the reference.

Answer (score 22):

From the manual for [call_user_func()](http://www.php.net/call_user_func)

> Note that the parameters for call_user_func() are not passed by reference.

So yea, there is your answer. However, there is a way around it, again reading through the [manual](http://www.php.net/call_user_func)

```
call_user_func_array('test', array(&$b));
```

Should be able to pass it by reference.

Comment: However, that workaround only works prior to PHP 5.3, according to the manual.

Comment: Yea, that is true, so it would probably be best to avoid using that method given it would not be forward compatible.

Comment: >Note This will not work for PHP > 5.3.0, so use it with caution.

however I just tried on PHP 5.3.3 and it worked without any warning/notices.

its seems call_user_func_array hide errors.

Comment: I did but there is another question about using call_user_func_array('test', array(&$b));
with 5.3.

manual says it is not allowed but in practice I see the oposit.

Answer (score 5):

I've just had the same problem, changing (in my case):

```
$result = call_user_func($this->_eventHandler[$handlerName][$i], $this, $event);
```

to

```
$result = call_user_func($this->_eventHandler[$handlerName][$i], &$this, &$event);
```

seem to work just fine in php 5.3.

It's not even a workaround I think, it's just doing what is told :-)

Comment: deprecated method.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the variable equal to the result of the function, like so...

```
$b = call_user_func('test', $b);
```

and the function should be written as follows...

```
function test($a) {
    ...
    return $a
}
```

The other pass by reference work-a-rounds are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the closure concept with a reference variable tucked into the "use" declaration. For example:

```
$note = 'before';
$cbl = function( $msg ) use ( &$note )
{
    echo "Inside callable with $note and $msg\n";
    $note = "$msg has been noted";
};
call_user_func( $cbl, 'after' );
echo "$note\n";
```

Bit of a workaround for your original problem but if you have a function that needs call by reference, you can wrap a callable closure around it, and then execute the closure via call_user_func().