# Php Code showing Following error in the webpage

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

am using joomla .. , 
by runnig the joomla it showing  the following error in the link part 
and the main error is about the parameter is expecting to a reference.
if i change it , it will not show any links

> Warning: Parameter 2 to modChrome_artblock() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\Site\templates\a_2\html\modules.php on
>   line 36
>
> Warning: Parameter 3 to modChrome_artblock() expected to be a
>   reference, value given in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\site\templates\a_2\html\modules.php on
>   line 36

and the php code on this error is

```
 - <?php
           defined('_JEXEC') or die;

           if (!defined('_ARTX_FUNCTIONS'))
             require_once dirname(__FILE__) . str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/../functions.php');

           function modChrome_artstyle($module, &$params, &$attribs)
           {
             $style = isset($attribs['artstyle']) ? $attribs['artstyle'] : 'art-nostyle';
             $styles = array(
               'art-nostyle' => 'modChrome_artnostyle',
               'art-block' => 'modChrome_artblock',
               'art-article' => 'modChrome_artarticle',
               'art-vmenu' => 'modChrome_artvmenu'
             );
             // moduleclass_sfx support:
             //  '' or 'suffix'   - the default module style: custom suffix will not be added to the module tag
             //                     but will be added to the module elements.
             //  ' suffix'        - adds suffix to the module as well as to the module elements.
             //  'art-...'        - overwrites the default module style.
             //  'suffix art-...' - overwrites the default style and adds suffix to the module and
             //                     to its elements, does not add art-... to the module elements.

             $classes = explode(' ', rtrim($params->get('moduleclass_sfx')));
             $keys = array_keys($styles);
             $art = array();
             foreach ($classes as $key => $class) {
               if (in_array($class, $keys)) {
                 $art[] = $class;
                 $classes[$key] = ' ';
               }
             }
             $classes = str_replace('  ', ' ', rtrim(implode(' ', $classes)));
             $style = count($art) ? array_pop($art) : $style;
             $params->set('moduleclass_sfx', $classes);


>  call_user_func($styles[$style], $module, $params, $attribs);

           }

           function modChrome_artnostyle($module, &$params, &$attribs)
           {
           if (!empty ($module->content)) : ?>
           <!-- begin nostyle -->
           <div class="art-nostyle<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
           <?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
           <h3><?php echo $module->title; ?></h3>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <!-- begin nostyle content -->
           <?php echo $module->content; ?>
           <!-- end nostyle content -->
           </div>
           <!-- end nostyle -->
           <?php endif;
           }

           function modChrome_artblock($module, &$params, &$attribs)
           {
             if (!empty ($module->content))
               echo artxBlock(($module->showtitle != 0) ? $module->title : '', $module->content,
                 $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));
           }

           function modChrome_artvmenu($module, &$params, &$attribs)
           {
             if (!empty ($module->content)) {
               if (function_exists('artxVMenuBlock'))
                 echo artxVMenuBlock(($module->showtitle != 0) ? $module->title : '', $module->content,
                   $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));
               else
                 echo artxBlock(($module->showtitle != 0) ? $module->title : '', $module->content,
                   $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'));
             }
           }

           function modChrome_artarticle($module, &$params, &$attribs)
           {
             if (!empty ($module->content)) {
               $data = array('classes' => $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), 'content' => $module->content);
               if ($module->showtitle != 0)
                 $data['header-text'] = $module->title;
               echo artxPost($data);
             }
           }
```

it showing the error

> call_user_func($styles[$style], $module, $params, $attribs);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the error "expected to be a reference, value given" appear?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637164/why-does-the-error-expected-to-be-a-reference-value-given-appear)

Comment: no it is not. i already gone through this link more than thrice

Comment: Did you try to change `call_user_func` to ` call_user_func_array`?

Comment: s same effect occur.. also by adding this,the menu(links) got dissapear

Comment: Can you show the exact like you written, calling `call_user_func_array`?

Comment: measn i change the code from `call_user_func` to ` call_user_func_array` only this much i done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following, it will solve your problem

> ***Go to Module -> Advance -> Module Style -> Change "inherited" to corresponding position styles. (e.g: select art-nostyle, art-block et)
>   in that case you don't have to scale down Php version***

*****it should open in joomla administrator, then do the above steps

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 function modChrome_artblock($module, $params, $attribs)
```

instead of

```
 function modChrome_artblock($module, &$params, &$attribs)
```